# Marketing Conversion Tag

Tags: magento2, tags

> Is anybody Implemented "Marketing Conversion Tag" pixel code?

I need pass some data to script which I did in magento1 but not an idea in Magento2.

```
    var rm_trans = {
        orderid : 'ORDERID',
        currency: 'CURRENCYCODE',
        customerStatus: 'CUSTOMER_STATUS',
        conversionType: 'Sale',
        customerID: 'CUSTOMER_ID',
        discountCode: 'DISCOUNT_CODE',
        discountAmount: DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
        taxAmount: TAX_AMOUNT,
        ranMID: ‘’,
        lineitems : [{
            quantity : QUANTITY_PURCHASED,
            unitPrice : SINGLE_UNIT_ITEM_PRICE,
            unitPriceLessTax: SINGLE_UNIT_ITEM_PRICE_NO_TAX,
            SKU: 'PRODUCT_SKU',
            productName: 'PRODUCT_NAME'
        }]
    };
```

We have two option for doing it:

1. By Directly Object Manager
2. By making a custom Module by passing DI

If anybody implemented it, please help me.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Is it google OR facebook pixel ?

Comment: No,this is any third party marketing tool.

Comment: Then you will have to do custom work for this.